# Узнать id для kill команды

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, терминал

Запустил node js код в терминале Ubuntu посредством node main_node.js&; обычно после выдает идентификационный номер. Чтобы отключить, необходимы команды =>
ps -ef | grep node
kill (определенный id).
сделал clear, забыв что у меня там этот идент-ый номер. Можно ли его узнать?

Comment: Совет: если не хочется разбираться с forever, можно для подключения/отключения к "консоли" nodejs использовать команду screen.

Comment: Ну вот представляете себе RDP-сессию, от которой можно отключиться, не завершая её? Похоже, только их может быть много, и они на локальной машине. То есть запустили в терминале screen, там запустили node.js (без &), отключились от сессии; запустили ещё одну, там ещё экземпляр node.js, отключились. А потом, если надо посмотреть, что они там в консоль понаписали, подключаетесь к которой хотите. google://"screen node.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже разобрался. После

```
ps -ef | grep node
```

появилась некоторая информация, среди которой была и эта:

```
hovhann+ 13564 13296  0 00:07 pts/0    00:00:00 node main_node.js
```

13564 и был этим самым идентификационным номером. 
после

```
kill 13564
```

отключается приложение node.

Comment: ``ps -A | grep node``

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще проще сделать

**#  killall node**